# Code Analyse in Visual Studio 2015 has problems

Tags: c#, visual-studio, code-analysis

I try to use a compliled assembly in my project and want to use CodeAnalysis build in Visual Studio. The Code Analsis is not running.

> MSBUILD : error : CA0055 : Could not load
>   C:\Code\Projects\UnitTestProject9\UnitTestProject9\bin\Debug\UnitTestProject9.dll.
>
> MSBUILD : error : CA0052 : No targets were selected.

after some problem investigation it could be the case that the commandline call to

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Team Tools\Static
>   Analysis Tools\FxCop\FxCopCmd.exe"

is to long (more than 13k characters) the problem is maybe the cmd max lengh of at least 8k characters.

Is there a solution to disable the add of all existing references (of all reference assemblies) to the call to FxCop.exe?

Comment: It is a simple file-not-found problem.  If you are 100% sure that the file in fact exists (look with Explorer) then you surely need to go shopping for another anti-malware product.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, unfortunatly the file is there and I think is not a problem of our AV, if i try to execute the call to fx cop I could not copy the whole line generated by vs to cmd ... this will only be happen if I use a reference to a assembly with a lot own references and no cls compliance.

Comment: Why use FxCop? There are other, more convenient and stable static analyzers. This is my personal opinion, and it may not coincide with yours, but I believe that FxCop is a rather weak static analyzer.